# How to print specific parts of an array of strings in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, insert

So I have a char array formed by words separated by spaces.
The array is read from the input. I would like to print the words that start with a vowel.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *insertt (char dest[100], const char sou[10], int poz) {

    int cnt=0;

    char *fine = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
    char *aux = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);

    strncpy(fine,dest,poz);

    strcat(fine,sou);

    do {
        aux[cnt]=dest[poz];
        poz++;
        cnt++;
    }
    while (poz<=strlen(dest));

    strcat(fine,aux);
    free(aux);

    return fine;
    } 


int check_vowel(char s) {
    switch (s) {
        case 'a':
        case 'e':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
        case 'u':
        case 'A':
        case 'E':
        case 'I':
        case 'O':
        case 'U':
            return 1;
        default: return 0;

    }
}

    int main (void) {

        const char spc[]=" ";
        char s[100];
        char *finale = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);
        int beg,len,aux; //beg - beginning; len - length;
        int i = 0;


        printf("s=");
        gets(s);


        finale = insertt(s,spc,0); //the array will start with a space

        do {
           if (finale[i]==' ' && check_vowel(finale[i+1])==1) {
               beg=i+1; //set start point
               do { //calculate length of the word that starts with a vowel
                    len++;
               }        
               while(finale[len]!=' '); //stop if a space is found
                   printf("%.*s\n", len, finale + beg); //print the word
           }

        i++;
        }
        while (i<=strlen(finale)); //stop if we reached the end of the string

        free(finale);
        return 0;


    }
```

The check_vowel function will return 1 if the character is a vowel, otherwise, it returns 0.
The insertt function will insert a **const char** into a **char** from a specified position, I used it to insert a space at the beginning of the array.

```
The input: today Ollie was ill
The output: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Preferred output: 
Ollie
ill
```

I'm sure the problem is somewhere in the main do-while loop, but I just can't figure out what might be it...
The 2 functions work correctly.
Thanks!

Comment: As I said, the 2 functions (insertt and check vowel) work correctly, they do exactly what they are supposed to do :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to read the input into array of strings?

Comment: works for me:jrenner@pc:~$ ./test 
s=today Ollie was ill
Ollie 
ill

Comment: your `fine` and `aux` variables in `insertt()` are only 3 characters long

Comment: A finite state machine would only need three states and three token types.

Comment: **[Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are lot many errors in your program that may cause a `SIGSEGV`.

1) The `fine` & `aux` pointers in the function `insertt` haven't been allocated with sufficient amount of memory. Change it to say:

```
char *fine = malloc(sizeof(char) * 300);
```

2) In the outer `do while{}` loop, the condition must be:

```
i<strlen(finale)
```

3) In the inner `do while{}`, the condition must be:

```
while(len<strlen(finale) && finale[len]!=' ');
```

**EDIT**:

There is still a `logical error` in your code, which I leave it to you to figure it out:

For string:

```
adfajf isafdadsf ifsfd
```

Your output was:

```
adfajf 
isafdadsf ifsfd
ifsfd
```

which is incorrect!!

Comment: Please don't suggest casting the return value of `malloc()`, even if OP's code includes that mistake.

Comment: Hey! Thank you! After applying your suggestions, it doesn't core dump anymore. I also noticed that there might be a logical error but I couldn't figure out where... Anyways, for "adfajf isafdadsf ifsfd" my output is: 
`adfajf isafdadsf ifsfd\n
isafdadsf ifsfd\n
ifsfd\n`

It's weird but I'll search around the code for that logical mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach, using a small finite state machine. The string is modified *in place*. The strategic use of `break` and `continue` avoids a lot of conditionals.
 (the only remaining condition it the for the addition of a space before the second and next selected words)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int classify(int ch)
{
switch(ch) {
case 'a': case 'A':
case 'e': case 'E':
case 'i': case 'I':
case 'o': case 'O':
case 'u': case 'U':
case 'y':case 'Y':
        return 1;
case ' ': case '\t': case '\n':
        return 0;
default:
        return 2;
        }
}

size_t klinkers_only(char *str)
{
size_t src,dst;
int type,state;

for (state=0, src=dst=0; str[src] ; src++) {
        type = classify( str[src] );
        switch(state) {
        case 0: /* initial */
                if (type == 1) { state =1; if (dst>0) str[dst++] = ' '; break; }
                if (type == 2) { state =2; }
                continue;
        case 1: /* in vowel word */
                if (type == 0) { state=0; continue; }
                break;
        case 2: /* in suppressed word */
                if (type == 0) { state=0; }
                continue;
                }
        str[dst++] = str[src];
        }

str[dst] = 0;
return dst;
}
int main(void)
{
size_t len;
char string[] = "abc def gh ijk lmn opq rst uvw xyz";

printf("String:='%s'\n", string );

len = klinkers_only(string);
printf("Return= %zu, String:='%s'\n", len, string );

return 0;
}
```